# jQuery scroll function is scrolling past top of div with element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this function to scroll down the page from one element to another. Everything works fine, except that with this function, it scrolls to halfway down the div, instead of just scrolling to the top of the div. How can I fix this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.request-tour-scroll').click(function () {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(document).height() }, 2000, function () {
            jQuery('#show').focus();
        });
        jQuery('#tour-option-section').css('display', '');
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Could there be some padding or margin added to the top of the section you are scrolling to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scrollTop call needs to have the scroll position set to the top of the div you want to scroll to, not the height of the document.

```
jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#tour-option-section').offset().top  }, 2000, function () {
    jQuery('#show').focus();
});
```

Codepen for example: https://codepen.io/jamiecalder/pen/LYYVqqX